# passing php array to javascript using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I'm building something with Google Maps and Instagram. I'm trying to send the coordinates of the Instagram photos from my PHP file to my JavaScript file using AJAX. I basically have no idea how to handle this on the JavaScript side.

This is what my index.php file looks like:

```
<?php

$jsonText= file_get_contents("");

$instagram = json_decode($jsonText);


foreach ($instagram->data as $photo) {

$longitude = $photo->location->longitude;
$latitude = $photo->location->latitude;
$picture = $photo->images->thumbnail->url;

$results = array($latitude, $longitude, $picture);
echo json_encode($results, true);
}
?>
```

My js file looks like this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.525961, 15.255119)
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);



$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

        var location = new google.maps.LatLng();

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map,
            title:"Where the photo was taken.."
        });
    }
})

}
```

Comment: Just put your marker creation in a loop and loop through your json results creating new markers of the data

Comment: @JoeSwindell But how do I use the coordinates I send? I can't just do 'var location = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);'

Comment: Sure you can. Put it in a loop, and with each location it creates push it to an array. Then you'll have an array of map locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest you not to share your API Key/Access Token publicly.

I made slight changes to your code. This is the ajax call now,

```
$.ajax({url: 'test.php'}).done(function(data) {
            // alert(data);
            for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                for (var j = data[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    $("#someElement").append(data[i][j]);
                };
            };
        }
);
```

You can use the data as you wish.